# Volvo C70 2009 Convertible ceiling panels: glue has come loose

Tags: volvo, interior

My friend attempted this repair with some kind of all-purpose glue which did not hold.  What is the best adhesive for this type of application?  As you can see from the photos, the ceiling panels attach to the roof via plastic feet.

Also, the plastic feet attach to the roof via slide-out posts.  I am thinking the best approach is to remove the panel completely, then re-glue the feet back on, then all I have to do is line up the posts to reattach to the ceiling.  Does anyone have experience with this type of repair?  I don't want to open a can of worms trying to attach the panel back on.  Thanks!

[image: top of ceiling panel]
[image: ceiling panel foot]